# Prolog -- How to tell if two things belong to the same group?

Tags: prolog

This is probably a very easy question -- I'm just learning and stuck on it though.

Say I have something like:

```
%facts
car(blah1, red).
car(blah2, blue).
car(blah3, red).
car(blah4, red).
car(blah5, black).
```

And now I want to make a rule where if I type in 'blah' I will get back all the blahs that are also red. So, for example,

```
%rule
is_same(Blah_x, Blah_y) :-
```

And if I entered `is_same(blah1, X)` the return would be `X = blah1, X = blah3, X = blah4`.  Where as if I entered `is_same(blah1, blah2)` no is returned (because `blah1` is `red` and `blah2` is `blue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking for:

```
is_same(X, Y) :- car(X, Color), car(Y, Color).
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- is_same(blah1, X).
X = blah1 ;
X = blah3 ;
X = blah4.

?- is_same(blah1, blah3).
true .

?- is_same(blah1, blah2).
false.
```